# Google Earth Engine: Sentinel-2 AOT band resolution

Tags: python, gdal, google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, geemap

In the  GEE documentation of Sentinel-2 Surface Reflectance dataset ([here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR#bands)) the information given is that there is a band for AOT (Aerosol Optical thickness) with a 10m resolution.
However, when loading data from this band, the resolution I get is only 100m.

What is the reason for the discrepancy here and how can I access data for AOT with 10m resolution?

This is how I load the data via the Python API:

```
collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_SR') \
.filterBounds(ee_roi) \
.filterDate('2018-01-01', '2019-01-01') \
.select(['AOT'])
```

Here the crs_transforms schows that the reolution is indeed 10m:

```
img = collection.first()
img.getInfo()['bands'][0]['crs_transform']

Out: [10, 0, 600000, 0, -10, 5400000]
```

Then I download the images:

```
geemap.ee_export_image_collection(collection, out_dir=save_dir, file_per_band=True)
```

and load them using gdal, which turns out to be an image with 100m resolution:

```
ds = gdal.Open(tif_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
ds.GetGeoTransform()

Out: (599900.0, 100.0, 0.0, 5400100.0, 0.0, -100.0)
```

So maybe the problem occurs when exporting the images.

Comment: As per the [help/behavior] please do not include chit chit like thanks, other statements of appreciation and a signature in your posts.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you think you're seeing 100m pixels; the crs_transform of the band clearly shows that the pixels are 10m in size, and displaying the image, you can clearly see 10m boundaries on the pixels.

[image: inspecting the AOT band]

[image: displayed on the map]

The [S2 Level 2 documentation](https://sentinels.copernicus.eu/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/processing-levels/level-2) describes that band as being resampled from 20m

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you are totally right! The images do have 10m resolution. Then I wonder if maybe the problem lies in the exporting of th eimages? Or with gdal?
(I edited the description to include the code I am using to export the images)